# Getting Source MAC Address from ether_addr

Tags: c, ethernet, libpcap

I am writing a program in C that reads packets using libpcap, and then outputs information such as the destination and source addresses. I am new to network programming, so I can't understand the output discrepancy that I am getting. I always get the correct destination MAC address, but incorrect source address.

Here is what the expected output is supposed to be:

**Packet number: 1  Packet Len: 42
Dest MAC: ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
Source MAC: 0:2:2d:90:75:89**

Here is my output:

**Packet Len: 42
Dest MAC: ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
Source MAC: 0:0:c0:a8:1:1**

I know that in the ethernet header the source address immediately follows the destination address, so I created my own struct to reflect this:

```
typedef struct __attribute__((__packed__)) EtherHeader {
   const struct ether_addr destAddr[6];
   const struct ether_addr sourceAddr[6];
   uint8_t protocol; 
}EtherHeader;
```

Here is a snippet of my code that attempts to get the addresses:

```
char *fileName = argv[1];
char errbuf[100];
const struct EtherHeader *eth;

pcap_t *handle = pcap_open_offline(fileName, errbuf);
struct pcap_pkthdr pktHdr = calloc(1, sizeof(struct pcap_pkthdr));
const u_char *nextPkt = pcap_next(handle, pktHdr); 
int packNum = 0;

nextPkt = pcap_next(handle, pktHdr); 
printf("Packet number: %d  Packet Len: %d\n", packNum, pktHdr->len);
eth = (EtherHeader *)nextPkt;
printf("Dest MAC: %s\n", ether_ntoa(eth->destAddr));
printf("Source MAC: %s\n", ether_ntoa(eth->sourceAddr));
```

I also need to determine what protocol the packet contains. How would I get to the packet segment that has that? Is it the remaining two bytes in the header?

Any additional things I should watch out for would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Note that on Linux `struct ether_header` is already defined in `/usr/include/net/ethernet.h` : `struct ether_header
{                               
  u_int8_t  ether_dhost[ETH_ALEN];      /* destination eth addr */
  u_int8_t  ether_shost[ETH_ALEN];      /* source ether addr    */
  u_int16_t ether_type;                 /* packet type ID field */
} __attribute__ ((__packed__));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`struct ether_addr` is already defined as a struct containing 6 bytes, so you
should replace

```
const struct ether_addr destAddr[6];
const struct ether_addr sourceAddr[6];
```

by

```
const struct ether_addr destAddr;
const struct ether_addr sourceAddr;
```

Note that you need an address-of operator `&` when printing the EtherNet addresses:

```
printf("Dest MAC: %s\n", ether_ntoa(&eth->destAddr));
printf("Source MAC: %s\n", ether_ntoa(&eth->sourceAddr));
```

(What happened in your case that the destination address what put into `destAddr[0]`,
the source address into `destAddr[1]` and the protocol into the first byte of
`destAddr[2]`.)

Comment: Thank you, it worked. In another question, for IP and TCP headers, how would I isolate just the checksum part? I originally thought of using bitwise operations, but then I realized that would mean shifting a mask by more than 32 bits, which doesn't seem to be allowed in C.

Comment: @user2259530: I don't know, so I would suggest that you start a fresh question. - If this answer solved your problem, please consider to "accept" it by clicking on the check mark.